# HX711 amplifier

Tags: arduino, sensor, adc, integrated-circuit

I have one of the [HX711](http://www.dfrobot.com/image/data/SEN0160/hx711_english.pdf) ADC devices that I want to use for a weighing application.
I've fitted it to a breadboard and used demo [firmware](https://github.com/bogde/HX711) to poll the chip for readings.
The behaviour is as follows: The ADC uses a PNP transistor to control the voltage that excites the bridge. The Base output from the ADC is right at VSUP, so no voltage goes to the bridge. [image]

Has anyone got success? failure? experience? with this device?
I'm confused as to whether the communications from the MCU enable the base to move below VSUP allowing the bridge to be excited.

Comment: What values of R1 and R2 have you used? It looks like the chip is designed to adjust the voltage at BASE until the voltage read at VFB is equal to the "reference bypass" voltage - 1.25 V.

Comment: It's one of the ebay boards, it looks like they assembled it. I had found some problems with my personal implementation (TX and RX weren't making contact in the breadboard) and the chip seems to require some communication before turning on the voltage adjuster.   Now that it's working, the VFB is 1.25 as you mentioned. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with wiring (Tx and Rx not making contact), 
Note- the voltage adjuster doesn't seem to start until communications from the MCU have taken place.